# Using GREP to find if each line of a file is found in a particular folder

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, grep, find

I'm using Ubuntu and I have a list of files from a

```
 find > list.txt
```

So there's 7,000+ files and each file is it's own line on list.txt, I was wondering if there's a search that would look for the file/folder from each line in list.txt to search a directory to see if it's found.

So basically in list.txt there is

```
 index.php
 styles.css
 image.png
 dothis.js
 image.jpg
```

I'd need a search would search a directory for index.php then for styles.css then image.png that way I don't have to look up each file individually.

Anybody ever done anything like this or have any ideas?

Comment: why not `egrep 'index.php|styles.css|image.png' list.txt` . If not, please indicate what you expect your sample output to be. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Shellter the problem is there's 7,000+ files so I was hoping to automate this as much as possible.

Comment: then I  don't understand your problem. Please illustrate required output. I'm assuming that you're just trying to "filter" your list.txt for index.php, sytles.css, etc. Otherwise choroba's response looks appropriate.  Good luck.

Comment: @Eric Some things aren't clear. Do you have only filenames or paths in your `list.txt`? And, do you need to do a recursive search for the file or just check if it's in some directory?

Comment: Basically for each line of the file that is searched I'd like an output of what file it's found in or if there's none at all.

Also @BroSlow I currently had paths but I could get those paths down to just the filenames if need may be.  This would be a recursive search throughout multiple directories.

Answer (score 3):

Untested, something along the lines of the following should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file ; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || echo $file missing.
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Maybe some double quotes around `$file`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Not needed in `[[ ... ]]`, possibly in `echo`.